# how to pass empty value to php cli

Tags: php

Like the title, I have a php script :
    demo.php
and run via php cli:

```
demo.php val1 val2
```

so how to pass val1=empty value to php cli?

```
demo.php '' val2
```

I want to get the `val1` to be `empty` or null

Comment: What did `demo.php '' val2` do?

Comment: demo.php is to update record in mysql, like `update from tbName set name='value1' where name='value2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your parameters:

```
php demo.php -a "val1" -b "val2"
```

The code:

```
$options = getopt('a:b:');

if (isset($options['a'])) { /* param "a" has been provided */ }
if (isset($options['b'])) { /* param "b" has been provided */ }
```